# Boolean values in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define true (lambda (x y) x))

(define false (lambda (x y) y))
```

So `(true 1 2)` will give 1, while `(false 1 2)` gives 2.

Based on this, how should I write a `(not true)` procedure which will give false and `(not false)` will give me a true using lambda expressions. (As simply as I can.)

`(define not p)` ...etc

Comment: `(define not (lambda (b) (lambda (x y) (b y x))))`

Comment: Or: `(define not (lambda (b) (b false true)))`

Answer (score 1):

So, @PetSerAl is absolutely right that the correct answer to this (if we are looking for a lambda-calculus-esque solution) is:

```
(define not
  (lambda (b)
    (lambda (x y) (b y x))))
```

Thus: `((not true) 1 2)` gives `2` and `((not false) 1 2)` gives `1`.

But since you didn't specify lambda calculus in your question, but instead tagged both Racket and Scheme, I will give you an answer that works there.

Consider if you have `true` and `false` defined as above. Then writing `not` is as simple as:

```
(define not
  (lambda (x)
    (cond [(equal? x true) false]
          [(equal? x false) true]
          [else (error "Value is not true or false")])))
```

This has the same semantics listed above: `((not true) 1 2)` gives `2` and `((not false) 1 2)` gives `1`. But it has the added benefit that you can actually directly examine it to see the value, rather than just applying it to another procedure. For example:

```
> (not true)
#<procedure false>
> (not false)
#<procedure true>
```

You can even now use `equal?` (or really `eq?` on them), whereas before you would have always gotten `#f` if you tried that:

```
> (equal? (not true) false)
#t
> (equal? (not true) true)
#f
> (equal? (not false) true)
#t
> (equal? (not false) false)
#f
```

This leads to a whole discussion of PL theory about what can and cannot be decided with the lambda calculus. That I will elide here. But if you are interested, I recommend you check out [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262062755), or [that book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262162091).